# Can it be defined something like $D^{f(z)}$ operator?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fractional-calculus

I've heard about fractional calculus where you can extend derivatives (and integrals) to complex numbers so that $\frac{d^{z}}{dx^{z}}\equiv D^z$ is meaningful where $z=a+bi$.
So I was wondering if it is possible to definde something as $D^{f(z)}$ where $f(z)$ is a complex function

Comment: That might be possible. Someone would be more likely to try if they knew a use for such a construction. To start, youi would  want  to decide what that operator ought to be when $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: No particular interest, i was just curious if someone has worked on that before, so what are those advanced mathematics you are referring to?

Comment: I don't have any particular use in mind. Just wondering whether you were asking because you knew of one. Keep on being curious.